# loader no works in some index pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, loader

I have loader in _Layout who activates when I press submit button:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function () {
                $.blockUI({
                    message: $('#bloqueocarga'),
                    baseZ: 99999,
                    css: {
                        border: 'none',
                        backgroundColor: 'none',
                    },
                    overlayCSS: {
                        backgroundColor: '#fff',
                        opacity: 0.7,
                    }
                });
            });

<div id="bloqueocarga" style="display:none;">
        <img src="~/Content/loading.gif" />
    </div>
```

For some reason in some pages works and into anothers no:

Button of index page where it no works:

```
   <input type="submit" value="Generate" class="btn btn-xs" style="background-color:#3399FF;color:#FFFFFF" />
```

Button of index page where it works success:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-xs" style="background-color:#3399FF;color:#FFFFFF" />
```

As you can see there is not any difference, but I really don't know why no works in some pages. I debbug it with Chrome console and it load JS and div with .gif

Any other ideas why it no work just in some pages? Regards

Answer (score 0):

here DIV tag by default display none. so...

```
<div id="bloqueocarga" style="display:none;">
            <img src="~/Content/loading.gif" />
        </div>

    $('#bloqueocarga').show();
```

try it.